# How do I make my rocket go back to its position when hitting the border?

Tags: python, pgzero

I am new to programming and started with pygame zero. I am making a little game where you shoot a rocket to an alien. But my rocket keeps stuck to the border when fired, I made a reload function but I want it to go automatically ( when it hits the border or alien to go back to its normal position). Can anyone help me with that?

```
alien = Actor('alien', (100,100))
ship =Actor('ship', (500,400))
rocket_fire = Actor('rocket_fire', (500,400))


WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT =500

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    screen.blit('space_back', (0,0))
    rocket_fire.draw()
    ship.draw()
    alien.draw()

def move_ship(ship):
    if keyboard.left:
        ship.x -= 3
        rocket_fire.x -= 3

    elif keyboard.right:
        ship.x += 3
        rocket_fire.x += 3

    elif keyboard.space:
        animate(rocket_fire, pos = (ship.x,0))

    elif keyboard.r:
        rocket_fire.pos = (ship.x,ship.y)

def move_alien(alien):
    alien.right +=2

    if alien.left > WIDTH:
        alien.right = 0
    collide = rocket_fire.colliderect(alien)

    if collide == 0:
        alien.image = 'alien'
    elif collide == 1:
        alien.image = 'nuclear_explosion'

def update():
    rocket_fire.draw()
    ship.draw()
    alien.draw()
    move_ship(ship)
    move_alien(alien)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign the initial values to 'rocket_fire' after 'collide == 1'.

```
elif collide == 1:
    alien.image = 'nuclear_explosion'
    // rocket_fire = (500,400) -> this is just a representation to assign position; not accurate as per the code
```

Comment: It worked, but it only goes back when it collides with the alien actor. Can I do the same but if it hit the border?

Comment: Yes, you can try assigning the position value when rocket hits the border but you need to write a conditional statement for detection of the borders: If border, then assign position